# Android - Cant refresh webview from js interface

Tags: javascript, android, web-scraping, android-webview, jsoup

I have a webView, and I am scraping the HTML:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebScraper(), "HtmlViewer");
view.loadUrl("javascript:HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
"('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
```

And the parameter `html` contains the whole HTML page:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void showHTML(String html) {       
   scrapePage(html);
}
```

Now the problem is, sometimes my HTML page shows an error message if the data hasnt fully loaded, or AJAX calls failed. When that happens I want to refresh the page. So i did:

```
 if (matcher.find()) {
     id = matcher.group(1);

     getLecture(dom);
 } else {
     Log.d("errors", "looks like player didnt load try again by refreshing page");
     webView.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              webView.reload();
                            }
          });
     }
```

But it doesnt look like my `showHTML(String html)` method is called again after refreshing. I was hoping someone could help me.

thnkas

Answer (score 0):

Wait until the page has finished loading through the interface method `onPageFinished` (in the `WebViewClient` class) and then get the content of the page using the `evaluateJavascript` method. This way you can get the content of the site without using the JavaScriptInterface annotation

The code will look like this

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("<GET HTML>", new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Found HTML content: " + value);
        }
}
```